# Jmeter java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: jmeter, socketexception

I am running only 1 request, the request is working good in other machines but my Jmeter is returning
Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I have tried in both versions: 4.2 and 5.3

Answer (score 1):

The reasons could be numerous, we need to know more in order to be able to come up with the comprehensive solution. The same machines in terms of operating system/networking setup with the same [Java version](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.html) should behave the same way.

What you could try is:

1. [Enabling Java Network debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) by adding `javax.net.debug=all` line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. [Enabling JMeter Network debugging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) by adding `<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />` to *log4j2.xml* file (the same location, JMeter's "bin" folder)

Upon JMeter restart you will be able to see much more troubleshooting information in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), compare the output from your machine with one of the machines where the test succeeds, it should give you some insights.